# What does Numpy.Reshape() do in Input Vector Processing In Terms of Total Data

Tags: python, numpy, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am actively learning how to encode text-information into numerical format, then make it to be learned through RNN or LSTMs.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/text-generation-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

This guy has well abridged the essence of LSTM as a good tutorial I think,

and he's trying to let the LSTM model to leran the whole text of "Alice in Wonderland"

In the sample codes, here's what I don't understand clearly:

```
# reshape X to be [samples, time steps, features]
X = numpy.reshape(dataX, (n_patterns, seq_length, 1))
# normalize
X = X / float(n_vocab)
# one hot encode the output variable
y = np_utils.to_categorical(dataY)
```

here, especially the function `numpy.reshape()` converts the dataX into the format what we want.

But I can't understand that `n_patterns` which is just integer 144223 does, which is a just `len()` of dataX.

I mean, I know as he said in the tutorial post, it rescale whole dataX list element into 0-1 scale, but what I curious is about which operation done for dataX to be like that mathematically.

That's it.

Thx for your help and will learn harder!

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a discussion forum.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: Play with reshape on small arrays in an interactive python session.  Make sure you understand the concept of array shape,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to know `dataX.shape` to have a clear idea of what is going on.

```
X = numpy.reshape(dataX, (n_patterns, seq_length, 1))
```

`len(dataX)` is just `dataX.shape[0]`, the first dimension of the array.

A key point with `reshape` is that the total number of elements cannot change.  From that I deduce that `dataX.shape` is already `(n_patterns, seq_length)`, and that the `reshape` is just adding the trailing size 1 dimension.

It is doing so for the convenience of the LSTM code, as indicated by the comment, `[samples, time steps, features]`.

`reshape` does nothing to the values.  It just changes the shape of the array (technically it produces a new array with a new shape, but sharing the original data).